# How to separate key and value pair from an object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

I would like to seperate the key and value from an object in typescript for that i have used the following code which returns only values but keys are not displayed.

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(key=> {
    console.log('keys', data[key]);     
});
```

But when i use the below function in javascript it gives me the key and value correctly can anyone tell me how to do the same in typescript to get the key and values from an object.

```
angular.forEach(data, function (value, column) {
    columns.push(column);
    values.push(value);
  });
```

Comment: In your first snippet you can just add `console.log(key)` and it will display keys as wel

Comment: `data.forEach((data)=>console.log(data.key + " " + data.value));` pure Javascript way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you get with `data[key]` is the value:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    console.log('key', key);     
    console.log('value', data[key]);     
});
```

If you want to loop over an object, you can simply use `for...in` too:

```
for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log('key', key);
        console.log('value', data[key]);
    }
}
```